# Still not get my SoundCloud API key

Tags: soundcloud

I completed the formular to get an API key for my app, it's been more than two weeks and I did not receive an answer. How can I contact SoundCloud please ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their web page has contact information

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

They take 2-3 weeks before they respond.

Email api@soundcloud.com

You can also try calling help on +4930467247600 however they have not worked for me.

Lastly I read online that one person heard nothing from them for weeks and checked his SoundCloud developer page under 'YOUR APPS' and his app was there set up and with the client id and secret etc. He was just never informed that he got it. So hopefully that is the story in your case.