# Soundcloud Developer Key

Tags: soundcloud

I applied twice in the google forms for a developer key for soundcloud to use a widget on my website. It has been more than 3 weeks and I have still not got any reply from them. What do I do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442321/still-not-get-my-soundcloud-api-key?rq=1

Comment: Soundcloud's contact page says they answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you just have to wait until they respond. I have applied 3 times now and keep getting rejected and the response is a generic answer not explaining why you were denied. For me I think it is the APP URL, yet they don't explain, it is so frustrating.

Did you try email api@soundcloud.com on my first rejection they were very friendly and replied with advice, however second time they did not.

You can also try calling help on +4930467247600 however they have not worked for me.

Lastly I read online that one person heard nothing from them for weeks and checked his SoundCloud developer page under 'YOUR APPS' and his app was there set up and with the client id and secret etc. He was just never informed that he got it. So hopefully that is the story in your case.

Comment: I got a confirmation mail saying that my app has been approved but there is nothing under My Apps tab.

Comment: Oh I don't know Ambuj sorry. I would google twitter, and the soundcloud community blog

Comment: Ok. Not a problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For me it took four weeks. I contacted them via Twitter and Email. They responded but all they said was:

> "As mentioned previously, we’re currently working through applications
>   as quickly as possible, although there has recently been more requests
>   than usual lately causing delays.
>
> You should receive confirmation soon though."